# Triangulation of hypercubes into simplices

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

A square can be divided into two triangles. A 3-dimensional cube can be divided into 6 tetrahedrons. Into what number of simplices an n-dimensional hypercube can be divided? (For example, a 4-hypercube, or a 5-hypercube.)

Comment: Not sure, but a little sketching suggests that a 3D cube can be constructed from $5$ (not $6$) tetrahedrons. Can anyone verify?

Comment: Where does "6 tetrahedrons" come from? There is a subdivision into 5.

Comment: @AlexR Double check your work, it's really 6.

Comment: @ZhenLin No, it's 6.

Comment: Related: [MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/55027/48565).

Comment: @Spenser That would make me conjecture $n!$ as the answer... But I can't figure out where the problem is, a tetrahedron is defined by four vertices, i.e. two non-collinear lines.

Comment: @Spenser See the MO question and it's accepted answer. There is a $5$-triangulation and the problem is basically answered there in greatest detail. Voting to close.

Comment: The question is answered in detail at http://mathoverflow.net/q/55027/48565 (it's an open problem, upper and lower bounds exist)

Comment: @Spenser Five is possible. I didn't say the tetrahedra were all the same size and shape.

Comment: @AlexR Ok. I see that there is a triangulation into five, and the problem of finding the most efficient triangulation for all hypercubes is open. But there is also a simple triangulation (not optimal) into 6 simplicies which I am sure can be generalized to all hypercubes. This is this triangulation that seems to concern the OP.

Comment: The question should be rewritten by asking for simplices that are congruent.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before there are (unsurprisingly) many ways to triangulate the cube. However one easy (and sometimes useful) way to do this is: Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,...,d\}$. Then define
$S_\pi = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: 0 \leq x_{\pi(1)} \leq x_{\pi(2)}\leq ... \leq x_{\pi(d)} \leq 1 \}$. Clearly, $S_\pi$ is a simplex since it is described by $d+1$ linearly independent inequalities. Now the cube $[0,1]^d$ can be triangulated by all $S_\pi$ where $\pi$ ranges over all permutations of $\{1,2,...,d\}$. To check that these simplices have disjoint interior is an easy exercise. 
This method uses $d!$ simplices corresponding to $2! = 2$ in dimension 2 and $3!=6$ in dimension 3.

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the volume of a cone-like object
$$O = \bigcup_{t\in[0,h]} \{t\}\times \frac thA$$
Is given by $\mathrm{Vol}^n(O) = \frac hn \mathrm{Vol}^{n-1}(A)$ suggests that we need $n$ $(n-1)$-simplices to get from a $n-1$-hypercube (hyper-parallelepiped) to a $n$-hypercube, i.e.
$$N(n) = n \cdot N(n-1); \quad N(1) = 1 \Rightarrow N(n) = n!$$
Note that this only constitutes an upper bound. For 3D it gives $6$ when there is in fact a triangulation with only $5$ simplices.